# getParameter(); всегда возвращает null

Tags: java, null

Функция getParameter() не возвращает значение параметра.
Вот пример простенькой программки:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

/*
<APPLET code="Applet_Par" width=300 height=50>
<PARAM name="Message" value="Java makes Web move">
</APPLET>
*/

public class Applet_Par extends Applet{

    public void init(){
        setBackground(Color.green);
        setForeground(Color.red);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        String msg = getParameter("Message");
        if(msg == null){
            msg = "Message not found";}
        g.drawString("MSG: " + msg, 50, 30);

    }
}
```

Результатом программы будет "Message not found". Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так.

Comment: Ты уверен, что такой параметр существует?

Comment: Ну не знаю, я брал пример с книги Шилдта - "Java 8. Полное издание". Вот в принципе он тут есть https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html

Comment: На SO можно найти много тем, где автор находит ошибку в Шилдте. Книга хорошая, но ошибок там довольно-таки много, поэтому код из книги не аргумент его заведомой работоспособности.

Comment: Судя по докам, параметр возвращает не нул, когда он вами передан запросом при запуске этого кода. Вы, видимо, не передаёте значение. Покажите как вы сей код запускаете.

Comment: Ну не знаю, когда я убирал условие, мне в апплете отображалось значение null. И в каком смысле показать как я запускаю этот код? Я просто компилю этот код, получаю файлик и при помощи appletviewer уже смотрю на результат

Comment: Т.е вы таки явно не передаёте никакой строки при запуске. От того и получаете нулл.

Comment: Апплеты?? Омг зачем вы трогайте этот мусор. Изучите лучше что-нибудь полезное

Comment: appletviewer нужно первым параметром указать ".html" файл. Его содержимое должно совпадать с закомментированным куском в вашем коде. Тогда все работает.